# How to stub ActiveRecord connection object using RSpec 2.13+?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, rspec2

As given in [RSpec Mock 2.13](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks), I was trying to stub execute method of ActiveRecord like this,

```
allow(ActiveRecord::Base.connection).to receive(:execute).and_return(assigments)
```

I got this error

```
 Failure/Error: allow(ActiveRecord::Base.connection).to receive(:execute).and_return(assigments)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `allow' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2:0x007fd8c1501648>
```

However, I used the older syntax and it worked without any hiccups.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.should_receive(:execute).and_return(assigments)
```

How to i call this with RSpec 2 and above versions?

Comment: Are you using a version of rspec that has the new syntax?

Comment: @sevenseacat: Yes, i am using RSpec 2.13.0

Comment: Is this happening in the right context? Is this in a "before" block?